# How are lambda captures initialized in case of nested lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, language-lawyer

Okay, so this is right off the bat from [expr.prim.lambda]p16 in n3337.pdf. Below code is given as an example:

```
int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;
auto m1 = [a, &b, &c]() mutable
{
    auto m2 = [a, b, &c]() mutable
    {
        std::cout << a << b << c;     // Shouldn't this print 113 or 133?
        a = 4; b = 4; c = 4;
    };
    a = 3; b = 3; c = 3;
    m2();
};
a = 2; b = 2; c = 2;
m1();
std::cout << a << b << c;             // Okay, this prints 234
```

and that it shall generate below output:

> 123234

However, the way I have understood the text in [expr.prim.lambda] (which is somehow obviously flawed), I feel the output should be `113234`, specifically the value of `b` printed in `m2`. Below is my understanding/explanation:

When `std::cout << a << b << c;` is executed inside `m2`, as per [expr.prim.lambda]p16 (emphasis mine):

> If a lambda-expression m2 captures an entity and that entity is captured by an immediately enclosing lambda expression
>   m1, then m2’s capture is transformed as follows:
>
> — **if m1 captures the entity by copy, m2 captures the corresponding non-static data member of m1’s closure type;**

Therefore, the `a` inside `m2` shall capture the member generated to the corresponding `a` captured in the closure type `m1`. Since `a` in `m1` captures by copy, and `a` in `m2` also captures by copy, `a`'s value in `m2` should be `1`.

The standard goes on to say (again, emphasis mine):

> — **if m1 captures the entity by reference, m2 captures the *same entity* captured by m1.**

I believe "*same entity*" here refers to the entity captured by `m1` via reference, and when captured by `m2` it shall be - a reference to the same entity if it's a capture by reference, or a copy of it if it's a capture by copy.

Therefore for `b` in `m2` shall refer to the `b` defined outside both lambdas. The value of `b` in `m2` then should be `1` as `b` is also captured by copy.

Where am I going wrong? More specifically, when is `b` inside `m2` initialised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that whether a capture is by copy or by reference depends only on the lambda expression's own *lambda-introducer* (the initial `[]` part), per C++11 [expr.prim.lambda] paragraph 14 (or [C++17 [expr.prim.lambda.capture] paragraph 10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#capture-10)).

The pieces you quoted from C++11 [expr.prim.lambda]/16 (or the same in C++17 [expr.prim.lambda.capture]/13) change only what entity is captured, not the type of the capture. So in the example, the inner lambda used to initialize `m2` captures the `b` from the original definition, by copy.

Then, note C++11 [expr.prim.lambda]/21:

> When the *lambda-expression* is evaluated, the entities that are captured by copy are used to direct-initialize each corresponding non-static data member of the resulting closure object.

(C++17 [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#capture-15) starts out the same, but additional wording is added for the *init-capture* syntax like `[var=init]`.)

In the example, the inner *lambda-expression* for initializing `m2` is evaluated, and the closure object's member for `b` is initialized, each time `m1.operator()` is invoked, not in the order the *lambda-expression* appears in the code. Since the lambda for `m2` captures the original `b` by copy, it gets the value of that `b` at the time `m1` is called. If `m1` were called multiple times, that initial value for `b` could be different each time.

Comment: _[...], the inner lambda-expression for initializing `m2` is evaluated, and the closure object's member for `b` is initialized, each time `m1.operator()` is invoked, not in the order the lambda-expression appears in the code._ - can you cite references from the standard regarding this? Also, I can't find in the standard where it says when the lambda expression is evaluated.

Comment: There are no rules for when lambda expressions are evaluated, just rules for when general expressions are evaluated. The rules here are just simple well-known ones like "the statements in a function body or other compound block are evaluated in order" and "evaluating a statement which is a variable definition evaluates any initializers for the variable". So the inner lambda expression is evaluated during a call to the outer lambda expression body, for the same reasons that the following `a = 3;` ... `m2();` statements are evaluated right after that.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. I think what you said in last paragraph of your answer now makes sense. So basically when compiler sees `auto m1 = [a, &b, &c]() mutable {...};`, it creates a prvalue temporary closure object and initializes `m2` with it; which also involves creating(only for copy-capture) unnamed data-members in closure type and initializing them. Since the compound-statement of `m2` is what gets placed inside the function call operator, its execution is just like any other function and so, the closure object for `m1` gets created only when the function call operator is called, right?

Comment: Sounds accurate, except it seems like some of the `m1` and `m2` names are mixed up.

Comment: I think I was sleepy. Too bad the comments can't be modified.

Answer (score 3):

> — if `m1` captures the entity by reference, `m2` captures the same entity captured by `m1`.

Yes, so `b` in `m2`'s capture list captures not the reference itself (the capture of `m1`, that is), but the object that it points to.

But whether `m2` captures `b` by value or by reference is determined solely by what's written in `m2`'s capture list. There's no `&` before `b`, so `b` is captured by value.

> when is `b` inside `m2` initialised?

When control reaches `auto m2 = ...;`. At that point, the reference to `b` stored in `m1` is examined, and the object it points to is copied into `m2`.

---

Here's an easier explanation.

- When you capture a reference by value, you make a copy of the object that it points to.
- When you capture a reference by reference, you make a reference to the object that it points to.

Here, "capturing a reference" applies equally well to capturing actual references, and to capturing reference-captures of enclosing lambdas.

Comment: Regarding _[...],the reference to `b` stored in `m1` is examined, and the object it points to is copied into `m2`_, you mean this is examined during runtime/program execution, as opposed to compiler parsing the code? Also, how is the value examined in `b` at that time `2`? Just before call to  `m2();` is made, `a = 3; b = 3; c = 3;` value of `b` is changed to `3`. What gives?

Comment: @Cheshar I think yes, normally it happens at runtime. Under certain circumstances it might be decided at compile-time under the as-if rule. *"Also, how is the value examined in b at that time 2?"* Maybe I wasn't clear enough; I meant "examined when control reaches the declaration `auto m2 = ...` itself", rather than "when control enters `m2`".

Comment: _Also, how is the value examined in b at that time 2?_ - I guess I didn't put it correctly. What I meant and confused with was that how can `b` (captured by copy) in `m2` capture a value which is assigned at a later point of time in program to the `b` which is outside of both lambdas. But I think what @aschepler mentioned in his comments makes it kind of clear. Also, regarding  _the reference to b stored in m1 is examined_, you may want to correct this, since for reference-captures it is unspecified if any data members will be declared in the closure type.

Comment: @Cheshar Glad you figured it out! *"regarding the reference to b stored in m1 is examined, you may want to correct this"* Hmm, you're right. But I'm not sure how to reword that part without making it less clear.